# Why No Property Type Propagation with rdfs:subPropertyOf?

Tags: owl, semantic-web, rdfs

Suppose I have

`:hasParent rdfs:subPropertyOf :hasAncestor .
:hasAncestor rdf:type owl:TransitiveProperty .`

This has the satisfying result of inferring all true ancestor relationships given the parentage. But I'm surprised it doesn't have the negative side-effect of making `:hasParent` effectively transitive too. Doesn't `p rdfs:subPropertyOf q` mean p "inherits" q's meta-properties, including `a owl:TransitiveProperty`?

Seemingly asymmetrically, we see with `A rdfs:subClassOf B` and `B :hasFriend C` that `A :hasFriend C` also since `A rdf:type B`. Why doesn't this happen with sub-properties too?

Comment: I understand that inheritance isn't really a thing in semantic web, and instead we have just a few inference rules. And property behavior is independent of classes. I guess I just found this lack of inference unintuitive and would appreciate some explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stanislav has already given a good answer to this question. What I want to address here is the idea mentioned in the comment that "inheritance of classes" are asymmetric with "inheritance of properties".

**Object Orientation**

(1) In object oriented programming languages, when class `A` inherits from class `B`, it means that the set of all the instances of class `A` is a subset of the set of all the instances of class `B`. Moreover, because attributes belong to a specific class, it means class `A` will have all the attributes of class `B` (i.e.
class `A` inherits all the attributes of class `B`).

(2) When class `A` has an attribute `c` of type `C`, it states (more or less) that there is an association `c` between classes `A` and `C`.

**OWL/RDFS**

(1) A big difference with OWL/RDFS is that properties **do not** belong to a class. When we say that `A rdfs:subClassOf B`, we say that the set `A` is a subset of `B`. It says nothing more. As an example if we have

```
B a rdfs:Class .
B rdfs:label "Label for class B" .
A a rdfs:Class .
A rdfs:subClassOf B .
```

class `A` will **not** "inherit" the label of class `B`.

(2) Properties in OWL/RDFS are specified between instances, **not** between classes. I have written about [this](https://henrietteharmse.com/2018/06/22/a-common-misconception-regarding-owl-properties/) in detail on my blog. When you state that `P rdfs:subProperty R` it means that the set of pairs of individuals in `P` is a subset of the set of pairs of individuals in `R`.

**But Functional Properties are inherited...**

No, they are not. It just seems so due to the semantics of functional properties. If we have a property `R` that is functional it means a satisfying assignment for `R` can be `{(a,1), (b,2)}`. That is the same subject cannot be linked to 2 different objects. I.e. you cannot have `{(a,1), (a,2)}`.

Now, if you have that `P rdfs:subPropertyOf R`, `P` is subset of `R` and thus `P` will be functional as well. I.e. if `R = {(a,1), (b,2)}` any subset of `R` will be functional as well.

Comment: Thanks for the example of how `owl:FunctionalProperty` will seem to be "inherited" in `P rdfs:subPropertyOf R`, but in fact it is just a by product of `R` being functional. We could assign a few more relation tuples rendering P non-functional, but this would not throw an inconsistency.

Comment: Yes, it will not. Reasoners do not check for inconsistent roles. For more see [this](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/0e7c/3a5c414432ae5fad2205a88779723d42d903.pdf) paper.

Answer (score 3):

> Doesn't `P rdfs:subPropertyOf Q` mean `P` "inherits" `Q`'s meta-properties,
>    including `a owl:TransitiveProperty`?

In general, no.

- `P rdfs:subPropertyOf Q` [means](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-syntax/#Object_Subproperties) that `∀x∀y(P(x,y) → Q(x,y))` (1)
- `Q a owl:TransitiveProperty` [means](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-syntax/#Transitive_Object_Properties) that `∀x∀y∀z(Q(x,y) ∧ Q(y,z) → Q(x,z))` (2)

Unfortunately, (1) and (2) do not entail `∀x∀y∀z(P(x,y) ∧ P(y,z) → P(x,z))`.

You can find a countermodel [online](https://www.umsu.de/logik/trees/):

[image: countermodel]

By the way, a subproperty of a functional property is also functional.

Comment: Indeed. From these assumptions, we have Q(x,y), Q(y,z), so P(x,y), P(y,z), P(x,z), but nothing to imply anything further about Q.

Comment: This makes sense. But can you shed some light on this asymmetry between properties and classes? Does it have something to do with the fact that p and q are "instances" of rdf:Propery, whereas A and B are classes? In general, can I safely assume that no sort of propagation will happen down a sub-property chain?

Comment: It seems that a subproperty of functional property is functional... Unfortunately, I can't understand your example with classes. Which [pattern](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf11-mt/#patterns-of-rdfs-entailment-informative) do you mean?

Comment: @PanFrancisco I have tried to address your comment in my answer. I hope it helps.